# Different mod_ssl and openssl- would it work correctly?

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl

I have: openssl, apache, mod_ssl all compiled from sources.

If i recompile openssl (newer version) and install it in the location of the old openssl do i need to recompile mod_ssl as well?

When I get the header I get "Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1i mod_jk/1.2.48 Server " so it seems that it uses the newer openssl but i have the "old" mod_ssk (compiled with 1.1.1h.

Would it be necessary to recompile mod_ssl or not?

It seems to be working ok, I'm just worried that might be underlying problems that i don't see.